# Скрипт открытия блока - "А" с видео контентом, по клику на блок "Б". При этом в блоке "А" должны разъезжатся блоки "Д" (элементы)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим есть блок

```
<div class="A">
<div class="D1"</div>
<div class="D2"</div>
<div class="D3"</div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы по клику на этот блок, открывался блок "B" с видео-контентом на весь экран и была кнопка закрыть.
Прошу помогите

Comment: Так, хорошо - вам нужно что бы при клике на один блок, открывался другой. Но я не понял, в чём именно проблема?

Comment: Что за блоки "Б" и "В", где они и что из себя представляют? Что значит разъезжаться? Какой блок в итоге должен открываться и что вы вообще понимаете под "открываться"? Ничего не понятно из вопроса. Что из себя блоки "Д" представляют? Приведите хоть какой-то пример, даже пустой набросок из вопроса - не валидный.

Comment: https://ru.pinterest.com/pin/558024210072700132/ мне нужно добиться такого эфекта но с видео